# Values not appending to my NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to add some vales to a NSMutableDictionary dynamically. However, using the following code, I'm adding values using the first letter as the key to a temporary dictionary and then finally adding it to my names dictionary but it just overwrites each value for it's corresponding key

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
for (NSString *drugStr in listContents) {
    NSString *substring = [drugStr substringToIndex:1];
    [dictionary setValue:drugStr forKey:substring];     
}
names = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
[dictionary release];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know that keys in a dictionary have to be unique? It seems from the code that if you have two drugs starting with the same letter in listContents, the second one will overwrite the value of the first one.

Comment: What do you mean by "it just overwrites each value for its corresponding key"? Are you trying to create arrays of all values starting with a particular letter?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you were hoping the code would do instead of "just overwrit[ing] each value for its corresponding key"? Suppose the list contained "aspirin", "paracetamol", "phentermine"; what do you want `names` to contain at the end and what are you getting instead?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce a plist which contains names that are categorised by their first letter, for instance 'Aspirin' and 'Annadin' would both come under the key 'A'. I know that keys have to be unique but I'm trying to add the value along with it's respective key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your NSDictionary to use NSString as a key, and NSArray as a value.

Then you should just retrieve your value according to the given key. If the result is nil, then you need to create a new NSMutableArray, to which you add the value above. IF the result is not-nil, add the value to the array.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
for (NSString *drugStr in listContents) {
    NSString *substring = [drugStr substringToIndex:1];
    NSMutableArray *valueArray = (NSMutableArray*)[dictionary objectForKey:substring];
     if(valueArray==nil){
         NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
         [newArray addObject:drugStr];
         [dictionary setObject:newArray forKey:substring];
     }else{
         [valueArray addObject:drugStr];
     }

}
names = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
[dictionary release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code worked but after adding it my app has slowed down considerably, can you see why?

Comment: Are you experiencing slowdown while creating the dictionary, or are there other slowdowns you didn't expect? This method does alloc a few mutable arrays while the function is running, but not to the extent that it should cause problems. What does the your xcode profiler say?

Comment: If I comment out the code the app runs ok, although I can't see why it would cause the effect it does. Not used the Xcode Profiler as far as I know, I assume it's in the Debugger.

Comment: So try running the xcode cpu profiler. It will tell you why your application is slowing down. I'm actually curious myself, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I ran the app through the cpu profiler and it showed mach_msg_trap running at 47.3% which broke down into mach_msg> _CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (Core Foundation) mach_port_insert_member, task_threads, task_suspend (libSystem.B.dylib). Under that is keyevent (24%) and _Bzero (22%)

Comment: Hmmmm... mach_msg_trap indicates your application is waiting half the time. Did you switching the sampling perspective to "running sample times" for the profiler? It could give a better indication of what your application is spending time on. BTW: How often are you running the function I posted in my answer? It shouldn't be run every repaint. "names" should only be created once, or every time there is a change in your listContents. If you're unsure how often the function is called, you can always add an NSLog() statement in the function and check the console output.